# Stop the character rendering on EditText in Android

Tags: android

Is that possible stop character rendering in EditText? In my code look like that

```
public class EditorActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(writerTextWatcher);

TextWatcher writerTextWatcher =  new TextWatcher()  {


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        System.out.println("afterTextChanged");
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        return ;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("beforeTextChanged");
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    System.out.println("onTextChanged");
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        return;
    }
};
}
```

I can't able to stop the char rendering in my editText. Please advice.

Thanks

S.Chinna

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete text when it changes - for user it will be seemed like nothing is rendered in editText.